# need help with sprintf usage in cakephp to delete data

Tags: cakephp

if i am using word link to delete as below

```
<?php 
 echo $this->Html->link(__('Delete', true), array('action' => 'delete', $company['Company'] ['id']), null, sprintf(__('Are you sure you want to delete # %s?', true), $company['Company']['id'])); 
?>
```

So there would be a confirmation message to delete the data.

But if i'm using an icon to delete info as below

```
<?php 
 echo $html->link( $html->image('delete.png'), $companydeletelink , array('escape' => false, 'title'=>'Delete', sprintf('Are you sure you want to delete # %s?')) ); 
?>
```

A warning will appear, andn also the message did not prompt.

Comment: What warning do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please post the warning you're getting here. I think there are a couple of things wrong with your second example:

1. the sprintf should have a second array providing the %s
2. the sprintf should be outside of the options array

   link( $html->image('delete.png'), $companydeletelink , array('escape' => false, 'title'=>'Delete'), sprintf('Are you sure you want to delete # %s?', array($example['Company']['id'])); 
   ?>

Comment: currently there is no error occurred. but then it will delete the data without pop up a confirmation message.

Comment: thanx Bjorn. finally the message pop up. thank u so much.really appreciate it. :)

Comment: You're welcome. If my answer solved your problem, please mark it as so (using the outlined check mark). :)